# my cosine won't accept my symbolic variable in matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, trigonometry

When I run the following code I get the error message:

> Undefined function 'cosd' for input arguments of type 'sym'.

What am I doing wrong?

```
syms a1 a2 a3     
F1 = cosd(a3)
```

Comment: Yeah thats the title of my question. What am I suppose to do to correct this?

Answer (score 5):

Obviously, MATLAB complains that `cosd` doesn't accept symbolic variables.

If you absolutely have to work with symbolic variables and degrees, use `sin` and `cos` instead, and convert the degrees to radians manually. For example, instead of `F1 = cosd(a3)` you can write:

```
F1 = cos(a3 * pi / 180);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`cosd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cosd.html) does not work with symbolic inputs. You should give it a double value.

Comment: I cant give it a double value, it needs to be symbolic if I understand this correctly.

Im using matlabs solve function and a3 is what I am going to determine

Comment: @MysGubbe - You really need to use solve, instead of just the acos function??????? Surely you can get degrees given a result in radians too. Multiplying by 180/pi would suffice. So WTP?

Comment: @MysGubbe - Then show a meaningful example that does not beg the question of why you could not solve a trivial problem. Applying solve to cosd is equivalent to use of a Mack truck to take a pea to Boston.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a quick fix:
[robotics toolbox not accepting symbolic inputs](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/robotics-tool-box/KIyY4Wmbymk/nP0cR58kBAAJ)

If you are talking about the cosd() function then it's stated cosd can't take symbolic inputs, you may change it to cos(i*pi/180)  , i being symbolic angle)  i will be in degrees . 
If you are taking  Regarding the robotic toolbox by Peter Corke , then check path of 
Rotation function, if it uses phase toolbox then shift path to the bottom.

Comment: How is the edited detail any different from EitanT's answer which was posted more than 5 years ago?

Comment: @SardarUsama  generally this problem appears with robotics toolbox that's why I added the "path fix"

Comment: The question has nothing to do with Robotics Toolbox